# How to make an if statement to select a string to show in a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, awt

currently I have two Checkboxes, one displays the text: " Numerical Grades", and the other one displays: "Letter grade". I also have a JComboBox with two strings(one are numbers, the other letters). So, my goal here is that when I select numeric grades the JComoBox shows me the numbers string, and viceversa.
I'm new at java, although I been trying to figure out how to do this for about two days, it didn't work so I hope you can help me.

English isn't my native language, so if I wrote something wrong I would be pleased that you correct it.

```
public void dropdownlist () {
    JComboBox list;
    boolean checked = rb1.getState();
    String[] numbers = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
    String[] letters = {"F", "D-", "D", "D+", "C-", "C", "C+", "B-", "B", "B+", "A-", "A"};

    if(rb1.getState()) {
        list = new JComboBox(numbers);
        panel.add(list);
        System.out.println("rb1 selected");
    } else {
        list = new JComboBox(letters);
        panel.add(list);
        System.out.println("rb2 selected");
    }

    list.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {


            });
     }
```

This is what I have so far.

Comment: Show some code, preferably a compiled program to work from.

Comment: @DSlomer64 I added some code of what I'am actually trying to do

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're asking "how do I display the right combo box".  I'm guessing you have a JComboBox with JRadioButtons inside.  If that is the case then something like:

```
{
...

ActionListener selectedActionListener = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
  {
    AbstractButton ab = (AbstractButton) ae.getSource();

    if ("Letter Grade".equals(ab.getText())
    {
      numericGradeComboBox.setVisible(false);
      letterGradeComboBox.setVisible(true);
    }
    else if ("Numeric Grade".equals(ab.getText())
    {
      letterGradeComboBox.setVisible(false);
      numericGradeComboBox.setVisible(true);
    }
  }};

  numericGradeComboBox.setActionListener(selectedActionListener);
  letterGradeComboBox.setActionListener(selectedActionListener);

....
}
```

Might work, but it would be easier to help if we could see some code.

Comment: And the stuff I put in the inner class would go in your lambda expression